# How can I select an optimal window for Short Time Fourier Transform?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, speech

I want to select an optimal window for STFT for different audio signals. For a signal with frequency contents from 10 Hz to 300 Hz what will be the appropriate window size ? similarly for a signal with frequency contents 2000 Hz to 20000 Hz, what will  be the optimal window size ?

I know that if a window size is 10 ms then this will give you a frequency resolution of about 100 Hz. But if the frequency contents in the signal lies from 100 Hz to 20000 HZ then 10 ms will be appropriate window size ? or we should go for some  other window size because of 20000 Hz frequency content in a signal ?

I know the classic "uncertainty principle" of the Fourier Transform. You can either have high resolution in time or high resolution in frequency but not both at the same time. The window lengths allow you to trade off between the two.

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Windowed analysis is designed for quasi-stationary signals. Quasi-stationary signals are signals which change over time but on some short period of time they might be considered stable.

One example of quasi-stationary signal is speech. Frequency components of this signal change over time when position of tongue and mouth changes, but on a short period of time approximately 0.01s they might be considered stable because tongue does not move this fast. The range of 0.01s is determined by our biology, we just can't move tongue faster than that.

Another example is music. When you touch the string you might consider it produces more or less stable sound for some short period of time. Usually 0.05 seconds. Within this period you might consider sound stable.

There might be other types of signals, for example, it might have frequency 10Ghz and be quasi-stationary of 1ms of time.

Windowed analysis allows to capture both stationary properties of signal and change of signal over time. Here it does not matter what sample rate does signal have, what frequency resolution do you need or what are the main harmonics. Are main harmonics near 100Hz or near 3000Hz. It is important on what period of time the signal is stationary and on what it can be considered as changing.

So for speech 25ms window is good just because speech is quasi-stationary on that range. For music you usually take longer windows because our fingers are moving slower than our mouth. You need to study your signal to decide optimal window length or you need to provide more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your "optimality" criteria.

For a desired frequency resolution, you need a length or window size of roughly Fs/df (or from a fraction to twice that length or more, depending on S/N and window).  However the length also needs to be similar to or shorter than the length of time during which your signal is stationary within your desired frequency resolution bounds.  This may not be possible or known, thus requiring you to specify which criteria (df vs. dt) is more important for your desired "optimality".

If multiple window lengths meet your criteria, then the shortest length that is a multiple of very small primes is likely to be the most computationally efficient for the following FFTs within an STFT computational sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed i was looking for such answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the sampling theorem, the sampling frequency needs to be larger than twice the highest frequency of the signal.  And based on DFT (discrete Fourier Transform), we also know that the frequency resolution is the inverse of the entire signal duration, and the the entire frequency span is the inverse of the time resolution.  Note that the frequency is simply the inverse of the period, thus the relationships go inversely with each other.

```
Frequency resolution = 1 / (overall time duration)

Frequency span = 1 / (time resolution)
```

Having said that, to process 20kHz audio signal, we need to sample in 40kHz.  And if we want to get the frequency resolution down, say to 10Hz, we will need to sample the entire duration as long as 0.1Sec, which is 1/10Hz.

This is the reason we normally see that audio files are said to be 44k.  Because the human hearing range is limited to 20kHz.  To add some margin to  it, we use 44k sampling frequency in stead of 40kHz.

I think the uncertainty principle goes with the fact that more localized signal in one domain, actually spread out on the other.  For example, a pulse in time domain goes from negative infinity to positive infinite, i.e the entire stretch of the spectrum.  And vice versa that the a single frequency signal in spectrum stretches from negative infinity to positive infinite in time domain.  This is simply because we had to go forever in order to know if a signal could be a pure sinusoidal signal or not.

But for DFT, we can always get the frequency span if we sample twice the highest frequency of the signal, and the resolution we want if we sample the signal duration long enough.  So, not so uncertain as the uncertainty principle says, as long as we know how many samples to take and how fast and how long to take them.

Comment: The question is about window size, not about sampling frequency or number of points in DFT