Setting window length and frame length in STFT for clustering audio
I am looking to understand better the consequences of setting the window and the fft length in the short time fourier transform  (STFT). My goal is increasing clustering of brief vocalisations (utterances) and I am trying to increase resolution of frequencies and squash the temporal component.
What are the effects of setting the: window frame > fft length,  window frame == fft length and  window frame < fft length ?

For clarity, I refer to:

window length : number of samples in each windowed segment of the input signal (which is frame_length in tensorflow and win_lengthin librosa, sometimes called fft_size in other packages)
hop : Number of samples between consecutive frames
fft_length : length of the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) applied to each frame (which is fft_length in tensorflow and n_fftin librosa)

Context
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866550/305883
I understand STFT works best for sounds considered stable, so for speech a good choice is to select the time during which sound is considered stable.
[2] https://www.researchgate.net/post/Fast_Fourier_Transform_FFT_for_soundscape_ecology_studies_how_to_determine_window_size_the_trade-off_between_time_and_frequency_resolution
In my case, I am working with animals, and I only can make an "informed" guess: I select the time span in ms, and select a window depending on the sampling rate (e.g. assuming 40 ms stability at 250000 sampling rate => 10000 frames, and 8192 window is the closest power of 2)
[3] https://support.ircam.fr/docs/AudioSculpt/3.0/co/FFT%20Size.html
I understand that window is the main parameter, and that I can increase the frequency resolution by increasing the window, and the ftt length.
The main param is the window. I can also oversample and interpolate the frames, by zero-padding, i.e. setting the fft length shorter than the window: fft length < window
However, this source also make clear that ftt is independent from the window, and that I could also setting wider.
[4] Indeed in Tensorflow I can set all the options - window frame > fft length,  window frame == fft length and  window frame < fft length.
But *not in Librosa, where must be ´fft length >= window´ Examples:
librosa.pyin(y, 
             sr=250000,
             frame_length=4096, 
             win_length=8192, 
           )

# ParameterError: win_length=8192 must be less than frame_length=4096


librosa.stft(y, n_fft=2048, hop_length=None, win_length=8192)

# ParameterError: Target size (2048) must be at least input size (8192)

I am confused by terminology and the errors.
Which would be the effect of  window frame > fft length,  window frame == fft length and  window frame < fft length ? Why FTT is independent from the window, but librosa enforce at least an equal or longer size, but Tensorflow allows any choice ?
Thanks for helping to understand and possibly contextualise to my challenge with some practical advices.

be aware there is No Free Lunch ... with FFT larger sample size of array fed into FFT call gives you greater frequency resolution in returned array  ... small number of input samples ( shorter window of samples )  results in larger frequency increments between the frequency bins which are elements of array returned from FFT call

Setting fft_size == window_length - FFT is performed on the window, nothing less, nothing more.
Setting fft_size > window_length - before applying FFT, zeroes are appended to the window, to match required fft_size. This operation does not add any more information, but increases frequency resolution of the resulting spectrum.
Setting fft_size < window_length  seems not good. It just crops window to match fft_size (according to this documentation of rfft).  Tensorflow allows us to make such mistake. Librosa assumes this is mistake and throws the error.
Feel free to add some clarification questions in comments

what if i set 'fft_size < window_length' with a hop, say fft_size and hop being half of the window ? I would crop the second half of the first window, but would I retain it at the second window ? or am i misunderstanding ?

@user305883 yes, but that would be very very unclean code. Probably, it would be equivalent of setting window_length, hop_size and fft_size to the same value, being half of the previous window_length (not sure how applying windowing function would impact this though).
